# Monstruous inequality $\Big(a^{(4b^2)^{4a^2}}+b^{(4a^2)^{4b^2}}\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\Big(a^{(4b^2)^{2b}}+b^{(4a^2)^{2a}}\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\geq 1$

Tags: inequality, exponentiation

Hi I want to solve this ,

> Let $a,b>0$ such that $a+b=1$ then we have :
>   $$\Big(a^{(4b^2)^{4a^2}}+b^{(4a^2)^{4b^2}}\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\Big(a^{(4b^2)^{2b}}+b^{(4a^2)^{2a}}\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\geq 1$$

I have try to replace $a$ and $b$ by $1-x$ and $x$ to see how monstruous it is ...

With wolfram alpha i try to calculate the power series but it becomes too complexe for me .

I try also trigonometry but it's awful .

With lucidity we need a book to solve this .

The equality occurs for $a=b=0.5$

Thanks a lot for sharing your time and knowledge

Comment: I like very much the title :-)....and after the question.

Comment: take log of both sides

Comment: Try using the properties of the logarithms to reduce the inequality to the form log (A) + log (B)> = 0, where A and B are sub-power expressions. Degrees 1/2 will be reduced. And then you need to "play" with these expressions.

Comment: Where did you find this inequality?

Comment: It might seem like the inequality would be even worse, but I think it would also be interesting to use $a=\frac 12+y,b=\frac 12-y$ for $y\in[0,\frac 12)$.  This approach would at least allow for seeing which terms are greater than $1$ or otherwise...

Comment: One further substitution that is possible (but doesn't appear to add much) is $a=\frac 1{1+z},b=\frac z{1+z},z\in(0,\infty)$.  The one potential benefit that seems usable is the numerator for $a$, since that portion always resolves to $1$ with any exponent in this inequality.  It is also possible to assume that $a\ge b$ and therefore use $z\in(0,1]$.